# Attempting a vertical carousel with pure JS and running into errors

Tags: javascript

What I am attempting to do is set up something similar to a vertical carousel, where the h1 within the "projects" ID will center when a keypress is selected respectively in the direction down and up.

I have attempted many different ways and have run into nothing but errors.

1. Attempting to change class (will be some code attached since this is the simpler concept).
2. Attempting to translate inline.

Both done unsuccessfully.

HTML:

```
<div id="projects" class="content middle">
  <div id="project1" class="items">
    <h1>Project 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="project2" class="items">
    <h1>Project 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="project3" class="items">
    <h1>Project 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (related, can provide more if needed):

```
.middle {
    transform: translate(0,0%);
}

.upper {
    transform: translate(0,50%);
}

.lower {
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}

.items {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
    top: -25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0%);
}

.items h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    font-size: 10rem;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #95cfb4;
}

.active h1 {
    color: #95cfb4;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #95cfb4;
}

.active h1:hover{
    font-size: 11rem;
}
```

JS:

```
// PROJECT SLIDER CONTENT EVENT //

var itemSlider = document.getElementById("projects");
var project1 = document.getElementById("project1");
var project2 = document.getElementById("project2");
var project3 = document.getElementById("project3");
var active = document.querySelector(".active");
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".items");
var currentItem = 1;

function translateUp(){
    if(itemSlider.classList == "lower"){
        itemSlider.classList.remove("lower");
        itemSlider.classList.add("middle");
    };
    if(itemSlider.classList == "middle"){
        itemSlider.classList.remove("middle");
        itemSlider.classList.add("upper");
    }
};

function translateDown(){
    if(itemSlider.classList == "upper"){
        itemSlider.classList.remove("upper");
        itemSlider.classList.add("middle");
    };
    if(itemSlider.classList == "middle"){
        itemSlider.classList.remove("middle");
        itemSlider.classList.add("lower");
    }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function checkKey(e){
    if(slideWrapper.classList == "projectsActive"){
        if(e.keyCode == "38"){
            translateUp();
        }
        if(e.keyCode == "40"){
            translateDown();
        }
    }
});

//**IDEALLY I WANT THE BELOW CODE TO WORK AS IT IS SET UP WITH THE ACTIVE 
//CLASS**//

listItems[currentItem].classList.add("active");

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if(slideWrapper.classList == "projectsActive"){
        switch(event.keyCode){
            case 38:
                listItems[currentItem].classList.remove("active");
                currentItem = currentItem > 0 ? --currentItem : 0;
                listItems[currentItem].classList.add("active");
                break;
            case 40:
                listItems[currentItem].classList.remove("active");
                currentItem = currentItem < listItems.length-1 ? ++currentItem : listItems.length-1;
                listItems[currentItem].classList.add("active");
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Ideally on the key press up I want the h1 above the middle h1 to push the middle h1 down and become centered vertically on the page (hence the translate), and opposite for the key press down.  I want this to be similar to a horizontal carousel.

DISCLAIMER -- I am attempting to improve in Javascript, hence the vanilla code.  Please forgive me if my coding is not up to standards as I am still actively teaching myself!